# How can I run and test my own written program on my original iPhone after jailbreaking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, jailbreak

I have done jailbreaking. After jailbreaking I don't know how to install my helloworld program on my iPhone. Plz can anyone tell me the easiest way of installing / deploying my own program / app on my my iphone (hardware) step by step? Plz I m very much confused. plz ....

Comment: If you are registered with ADC you should have no problem running to device, even if it is jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, Developing for a Jailbroken iPhone (iOS 4.0.1):

http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=398

Answer (score 0):

I was following this guide: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode
Actually I was performing only the first four steps, i.e. following Apples guide on selfsigning + editing the Info.plist file.

Originally I was copying my apps via ssh into the /Applications folder on the device.
Later I realised that I was also able to use Xcode to send the apps to the device via USB.
In that case the apps get copied into the folder /Users/Applications.